# Disable geolocation in Safari

Tags: mac, safari, geolocation, privacy

I have tried to check "Decline without asking" (Translated).

Now, it won't show where I am on maps and so, but even though I use VPN, Google/Facebook/Youtube and other websites know that I am in Sweden? How can I disable this? Say, I want websites to assume that I am in the UK, or in the USA?

Comment: did you disable the location service

Comment: Have you deleted your cache and cookies?

Comment: @AlexIxeras This question is almost 2 years old, but I figured they know where I am based on system/browser language.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser sends its list of preferred languages to websites. With other browsers, this is usually customizable, but not in Safari for macOS. On the Mac, Safari only sends the systemwide preferred languages.

To change it: **** → **System Preferences** → **Language & Region**.
***Beware that doing this will change the locale used by your operating system.***

On the other hand, in iOS 10 the systemwide language is set separately from the app-and-website preferred languages. Both can be found under **Settings** → **General** → **Language & Region**.

Answer (score 0):

> You can also turn Location Services off altogether by deselecting Enable Location Services in the Privacy pane of Security & Privacy preferences. Even if you disable Location Services, third party applications and websites may still use other ways to determine your location.
>
> To open the Privacy pane, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click Security & Privacy, then click Privacy.

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18649

Comment: I did this, and even when using a VPN, websites still show everything in Swedish. How can they determine my location?